# Java replace initial characters in String and preserve length

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

I'm looking for solution (Java) to replace the initial occurrences of multiple character with the same number of other character, for example if 'a' should be replaced with '-', than I expect:

```
aaabbaa  -> ---bbaa
aaxxaab  -> --xxaab
xaaaaax  -> xaaaaax
```

I've tried something like:

```
"aaabbaa".replaceAll( "^[a]+", "-")        // -bbaa
"aaabbaa".replaceAll( "(?=^[a]+)", "-")    // -aaabbaa
```

If possible, I prefer regex or oneliner.

Do you have any hints?

regards,
Annie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java supports finite repetition in a lookbehind. You could match a asserting what is on the left from the start of the string are only a's.

In the replacement using `-`

```
(?<=^a{1,100})a
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jeqTn3/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UXiTcq#stdin)

For example

```
System.out.println("aaabbaa".replaceAll("(?<=^a{0,100})a", "-"));
```

Output

```
---bbaa
```

Comment: perfect solution! 
I assume, this is also ok:
"aaabbbaaa".replaceAll( "(?<=^a*)a", "-")

Comment: @AnnieW. I have tested it and that also works https://ideone.com/npPlMN According to [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) `..for both correctness and performance, we recommend you only use quantifiers with a low upper bound in lookbehind with Java 6 through 13.`

Answer (score 4):

If using Java 9+, use the lambda overload for `replaceAll`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String res = Pattern
            .compile("^a+")
            .matcher("aaabbb")
            .replaceAll(m -> "-".repeat(m.group().length()));
        System.out.println(res); // => ---bbb
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `char[]`:

```
char[] cs = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length && cs[i] == 'a'; ++i) {
  cs[i] = '-';
}
String newStr = new String(cs);
```

Comment: Agreed. That condition stops the for loop. But honestly: what a horrible way to solve this problem.